# sumif関数の検索条件で、値の条件でなく書式の条件で合計したい。探しています。

Tags: google-apps-script, vba

1. 赤文字だけの（フォントの色指定）合計をしたい。
2. かっこの文字は、合計しない。

```
 10
(20)　←書式で(0)
 30
 40　　←合計=10+30　=MYsumif(かっこじゃない、A1:A3)
```

いい方法があったら教えて下さい。
エクセルVBA、GASです。よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: ①1列左に非表示列を、追加で対応できそうです。②合計から（）の合計をひく。

Comment: ②（）のため、1列設けるののも、わかりにくいですね。